# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<LanParties> has no method 'call'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to loop through a collection and render template for each model in the collection. What am I doing wrong?

Top level view:

```
class App.Views.Content extends Backbone.View
  className: 'views-container'

  template:  HandlebarsTemplates['app/templates/content']

  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template())
    @renderEmptyView()
    @renderLanParties()
    @

  renderEmptyView: ->
    v = new App.Views.Empty()
    @$('.content-wrapper').html(v.render().el)

  renderLanParties: ->
    v = new App.Views.LanParties({ collection: new App.Collections.LanParties })
    @$('.lan-list').html(v.render().el)
```

View rendering collection:

```
class App.Views.LanParties extends Backbone.View
  className: 'lan-parties-list'

  template:  HandlebarsTemplates['app/templates/lan_parties']

  initialize: ->
    @listenTo @collection, 'reset', @render()
    @collection.fetch({ reset: true })

  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template())
    @collection.forEach @renderLanParty, @
    @

  renderLanParty: (model) ->
    v = new App.Views.LanParty({ model: model })
    @$('ul').append(v.render().el)
```

The model:

```
class App.Models.LanParty extends Backbone.Model

class App.Collections.LanParties extends Backbone.Collection
  model:  App.Models.LanParty
  url: "/lan_parties"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In App.Views.LanParties don't call @render, change

```
@listenTo @collection, 'reset', @render()
```

to

```
@listenTo @collection, 'reset', @render
```

And you might want to instantiate new App.Collections.LanParties in App.Views.Content.